# Where to buy rare old LEGO sets?

Tags: technic, shopping, sets

Does anybody know a good place to buy rare old LEGO sets?

I'm looking specifically for old "pneumatic" featured LEGO Technic sets.

Comment: I'd try bricklink

Comment: search on Bricklink.com for the keyword "pneumatic". there you will get approx 40 different sets and their set-number. then seach on ebay for "lego + set number" , there is a lot to find. good luck and enjoy...

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a specific set in mind [BrickSet](https://brickset.com/) provides links to ebay, bricklink, etc. to get a good overall idea of what prices look like.  BrickSet also has a tag for [pneumatic sets](https://brickset.com/sets/tag-Pneumatic).  I use it for tracking my wish list and what I already have.

I usually end up buying the sets or parts on [BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page), but I'm not shopping for old sets that often.  There is much less sketchy stuff happening in BrickLink than on ebay.  You can find better prices if you're patient with ebay, but the BrickLink prices are often totally reasonable.  BrickLink also functions as the canonical list of sets and which parts are in which sets.  Sites like BrickSet automatically synchronize with it.

Looking at one of the oldest pneumatic sets - [8851 Excavator](https://brickset.com/sets/8851-1/Excavator) - ebay has it for $12 & $12.99.  [BrickLink's prices](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8851-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) start at at $39.67 so I'd probably see if the ebay seller's have high-enough ebay reputation to deal with.  In this case ebay might even require less patience than bricklink.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's very useful :)